# How to extract the body of a Section in a word document? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, python-docx

I have a document with the following structure.

***INPUT:***
[image: Screenshot]

***OUTPUT:***

```
Text
Text
Text
I want to extract this body
```

In the above image, I want to extract the text of Article I and II in Python. 
These Articles are actually sections, as you can see it on the left Navigation. Those are not raw text, I cannot select the Article, it is just like bullets. I tried the following code, which I found on StackOverflow.

```
import docx
document = docx.Document("rwi.docx")

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
        print(paragraph.text)
```

But this just prints the Heading Title but not the body (text) of the title. How can I extract the body of the titles?

Comment: This is a very nonspecific question and it is difficult to understand what you mean. Can you come with example input and ideal output as well?

Comment: I have added a screenshot, let me know if I am still not clear.

Comment: This was indeed clearer. A good idea whenever posting here is to do what you just did. Makes it very easy to know what the problem is.

Comment: I assume the error comes from the headings being paragraphs themselves. Try a for loop where you print out both the style and name, that might make it easier for you to figure out the correct approach.